# Seeing memory leaks from PHPickerViewController

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, phpickerviewcontroller

I've recently integrated the PHPickerViewController per Apple's recommendation for accessing photos within your app.  However, testing for memory leaks, I've noticed the picker is producing many memory leaks.  I'm running the PHPickerDemo and see the following leaks while profiling:

[Image from Instruments Memory Leaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPG2q.png)

Any thoughts on how to solve this or is this something we have to wait for Apple to fix?

Comment: I get these leaks whenever I use the picker to import a picture after a picture has already been imported. I suspect the picker is hanging onto the previous objects it imports, creating the leak.